# Prolog length to initialize list adds new List to existing Lists

Tags: list, prolog

```
puzzle(ListToAdd,ListToAdd1,Res,_,Carry) :-
   length(Res,ResultLength),
   length(Carry,ResultLength),
   domain(Carry,0,1).
```

First I use length to get the size of the Res list (ResultLength) and then I will use ResultLength to initialize the other list, Carry. 
However after I do that both ListoAdd and ListToAdd1 now have the aforementioned Carry list in them, which I belive it shouldn´t happen.

```
    Query done: puzzle([D,O,N,A,L,D],[G,E,R,A,L,D],[R,O,B,E,R,T],X,L).


        Before  length(Carry,ResultLength):
        write(ListToAdd):  [_5459,_5499,_5539,_5319]
        write(ListToAdd1): [_5199,_5239,_5279,_5319]

        After  length(Carry,ResultLength):
       write(Carry):      [_12043,_12107,_12171,_12235]
       write(ListToAdd):  [_5459,_5499,_5539, [_12043,_12107,_12171,_12235],_5319]
       write(ListToAdd1): [_5199,_5239,_5279, [_12043,_12107,_12171,_12235],_5319]
```

I´m using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Pay more attention to details. Your question could benefit, and you would get more and better answers!

Comment: such as? I'd very much appreciate if  you could provide one or two examples

Comment: "lenght", "ListoAdd", "then I will said size to initialize the list", `length(Carry,ResultLength)domain(Carry,0,1)`

Comment: Thanks, that is a result of my terrible writing skills, i will try and fix it a bit , thanks!

Comment: Also, if possible, do not add images of queries and answers. Directly add the info to your question using <pre>...</pre>.

Comment: Developing the right habits takes some time, but it's sure worth the effort.

Comment: I´ll try and do better from now own and thanks for the tips!

Comment: Good! Please provide more information so people can reproduce the problem you are having... Which Prolog processor are you using? Give concrete queries and answers. How do you get the info "before ... ListToAdd = ..."?

Comment: What query are you issuing to get these results?

Comment: "I´ll try and do better from now **own** and thanks for the tips!"  how ironic:)

Comment: Yeah, my writing needs to improve and ASAP xD 

 Note to self: Re-read more than once what you have written

Comment: That's the spirit! Keep it and you'll go far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the troubles you are experiencing is this:

```
?- puzzle([D,O,N,A,L,D],[G,E,R,A,L,D],[R,O,B,E,R,T],X,L).
```

Got it? If not, consider:

```
?- puzzle([D,O,N,A,L,D],[G,E,R,A,L,D],[R,O,B,E,R,T],X,L).
                   ^             ^                    ^
                   +-------------+--------------------+
```

Those logical variables:)

HTH!

Comment: Right now, I am in love with you xD I spent an entire afternoon on this and couldn´t for the life of me figure it out, Thank you very much!!

Comment: Alright! Next time provide all (potentially) relevant information ASAP.